# Determine if an executable (or library) is 32 -or 64-bits (on Windows)

Tags: python, windows, dll, 64-bit, executable

I am trying to find out if a given executable (or library) is compiled for 32-bits or 64-bits from Python. I am running Vista 64-bits and would like to determine if a certain application in a directory is compiled for 32-bits or 64-bits.

Is there a simple way to do this using only the standard Python libraries (currently using 2.5.4)?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The Windows API for this is [`GetBinaryType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364819(VS.85).aspx). You can call this from Python using [pywin32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/):

```
import win32file
type=GetBinaryType("myfile.exe")
if type==win32file.SCS_32BIT_BINARY:
    print "32 bit"
# And so on
```

If you want to do this without pywin32, you'll have to read the [PE header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_executable) yourself. Here's [an example](http://www.neowin.net/forum/index.php?showtopic=732648&st=0&p=590544108&#entry590544108) in C#, and here's a quick port to Python:

```
import struct

IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_I386=332
IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_IA64=512
IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_AMD64=34404

f=open("c:\windows\explorer.exe", "rb")

s=f.read(2)
if s!="MZ":
    print "Not an EXE file"
else:
    f.seek(60)
    s=f.read(4)
    header_offset=struct.unpack("<L", s)[0]
    f.seek(header_offset+4)
    s=f.read(2)
    machine=struct.unpack("<H", s)[0]

    if machine==IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_I386:
        print "IA-32 (32-bit x86)"
    elif machine==IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_IA64:
        print "IA-64 (Itanium)"
    elif machine==IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_AMD64:
        print "AMD64 (64-bit x86)"
    else:
        print "Unknown architecture"

f.close()
```

Comment: It would be nice if I could get this information without using the pywin32 module.

Comment: Just edited the answer to show how you can do this without pywin32.

Comment: @Martin. Thanks for the links, I will see if I can put something together.

Comment: Just added a port of the C# example to Python.

Comment: Shouldn't the file be opened in binary mode?

Comment: This prints "Unknown architecture" on my machine. The machine variable reports -31132. Any suggestions?

Comment: My bad -- IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_IA64 is Itanium. -31132 (or 34404 unsigned) is AMD64 (aka 64-bit x86). Don't have a 64-bit system I can test this on, but I hope it should work now.

Comment: I was able to use this solution (Python 3.5) after incorporating the changes suggested in the answer provided below by Jason R Coombs.

Comment: I don't think the `GetBinaryType` solution works for non-executables, e.g. this does not work for DLLs. The [GetBinaryTypeA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getbinarytypea) seems to indicate that it is only usable for detecting if a file is executable; return value is zero for DLLs, and `GetLastError` reports `ERROR_BAD_EXE_FORMAT`.

Answer (score 5):

If you're running Python 2.5 or later on Windows, you could also use the Windows API without pywin32 by using ctypes.

```
from ctypes import windll, POINTER
from ctypes.wintypes import LPWSTR, DWORD, BOOL

SCS_32BIT_BINARY = 0 # A 32-bit Windows-based application
SCS_64BIT_BINARY = 6 # A 64-bit Windows-based application
SCS_DOS_BINARY = 1 # An MS-DOS-based application
SCS_OS216_BINARY = 5 # A 16-bit OS/2-based application
SCS_PIF_BINARY = 3 # A PIF file that executes an MS-DOS-based application
SCS_POSIX_BINARY = 4 # A POSIX-based application
SCS_WOW_BINARY = 2 # A 16-bit Windows-based application

_GetBinaryType = windll.kernel32.GetBinaryTypeW
_GetBinaryType.argtypes = (LPWSTR, POINTER(DWORD))
_GetBinaryType.restype = BOOL

def GetBinaryType(filepath):
    res = DWORD()
    handle_nonzero_success(_GetBinaryType(filepath, res))
    return res
```

Then use GetBinaryType just like you would with win32file.GetBinaryType.

Note, you would have to implement handle_nonzero_success, which basically throws an exception if the return value is 0.

Answer (score 3):

I've edited [Martin B's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/134877/martin-b) answer to work with Python 3, added `with` statements and ARM/ARM64 support:

```py
import struct

IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_I386 = 332
IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_IA64 = 512
IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_AMD64 = 34404
IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_ARM = 452
IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_AARCH64 = 43620

with open('foo.exe', 'rb') as f:
    s = f.read(2)
    if s != b'MZ':
        print('Not an EXE file')
    else:
        f.seek(60)
        s = f.read(4)
        header_offset = struct.unpack('<L', s)[0]
        f.seek(header_offset + 4)
        s = f.read(2)
        machine = struct.unpack('<H', s)[0]

        if machine == IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_I386:
            print('IA-32 (32-bit x86)')
        elif machine == IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_IA64:
            print('IA-64 (Itanium)')
        elif machine == IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_AMD64:
            print('AMD64 (64-bit x86)')
        elif machine == IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_ARM:
            print('ARM eabi (32-bit)')
        elif machine == IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_AARCH64:
            print('AArch64 (ARM-64, 64-bit)')
        else:
            print(f'Unknown architecture {machine}')
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to use Martin B's answer successfully in a Python 3.5 program after making this adjustment:

```
s=f.read(2).decode(encoding="utf-8", errors="strict")
```

Originally it worked just fine with my program in Python 2.7, but after making other necessary changes, I discovered I was getting b'MZ', and decoding it appears to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

1. Using Python 3.7, 32 bit on 64 bit Win 7, the first code fragment in the top answer doesn't run for me.  It fails because GetBinaryType is an unknown symbol.  Solution is to use `win32file.GetBinaryType`.
2. Also running it on a .pyd file doesn't work, even if it is renamed to a .dll.  See next:

   ```
   import shutil

   import win32file
   from pathlib import Path

   myDir = Path("C:\\Users\\rdboylan\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python37\\site-packages\\pythonwin")
   for fn in ("Pythonwin.exe", "win32ui.pyd"):
       print(fn, end=": ")
       myf = myDir / fn
       if myf.suffix == ".pyd":
           mytemp = myf.with_suffix(".dll")
           if mytemp.exists():
               raise "Can not create temporary dll since {} exists".format(mytemp)
           shutil.copyfile(myf, mytemp)
           type = win32file.GetBinaryType(str(mytemp))
           mytemp.unlink()
       else:
           type=win32file.GetBinaryType(str(myf))
       if type==win32file.SCS_32BIT_BINARY:
           print("32 bit")
       else:
           print("Something else")
       # And so on
   ```

   Results in

   ```
   Pythonwin.exe: 32 bit
   win32ui.pyd: Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "C:/Users/rdboylan/Documents/Wk devel/bitness.py", line 14, in <module>
       type = win32file.GetBinaryType(str(mytemp))
   pywintypes.error: (193, 'GetBinaryType', '%1 is not a valid Win32 application.')
   ```