# Python and pygame error message "image not found"

Tags: python, pygame

I've installed python 3.8.7 on my mid 2009 macbook pro,and can't seem to properly install pygame on it. I've gone into terminal and installed it using the command "pip3 install pygame" which seemed to work fine, but when I try to import it in python it comes up with the error message "image not found". If anyone could help it would be greatly appreciated.

Error stack trace

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "/Users/user/Documents/check.py", 
line 1, in <module> import pygame File 
"/Users/user/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/pygame/__init__.py", 
line 81, in <module> from pygame.base import * # pylint: disable=wildcard- 
import; lgtm[py/polluting-import] ImportError: 
dlopen(/Users/user/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site- 
packages/pygame/base.cpython-38-darwin.soLibrary not loaded: 
/System/Library/Frameworks/Metal.framework/Versions/A/Metal Referenced from: 
/Users/user/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/pygame/base.cpython- 
38-darwin.so Reason: image not found
```

Comment: Ive not tried to load an image I've just imported pygame

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to import all images from a user specified folder in python using pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22420127/how-to-import-all-images-from-a-user-specified-folder-in-python-using-pygame)

Comment: I don't think it's about images cause I've not tried to import an image

Comment: Please post the _full_ error message including traceback, else it's hard to pinpoint the problem.

Comment: maybe pygame didn't install correctly. Half of my problems are solved by uninstalling and reinstalling things so try that.

Comment: It's too long I'll have to post in two parts

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/user/Documents/check.py", line 1, in <module>
import pygame
File "/Users/user/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/pygame/__init__.py", line 81, in <module>
from pygame.base import * # pylint: disable=wildcard-import; lgtm[py/polluting-import]
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/user/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/pygame/base.cpython-38-darwin.so, 2):

Comment: Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/Metal.framework/Versions/A/Metal
Referenced from: /Users/user/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/pygame/base.cpython-38-darwin.so
Reason: image not found

Comment: I've installed it and unistalled it like 1000 times

Comment: @AlixAddison Try `pip install --no-cache-dir <pygame >`

Answer (score -1):

as user "ModoUnreal" said in that post
([Error while import pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34315144/error-while-import-pygame/41325899))
"A. Check if you have a 64 or 32 bit version pygame and make sure your version of python is the same.

B. Use something like pip install or any other type of method to install pygame.

C. Install a previous version of pygame and python, you might have some more luck with that.

The error is basically saying that a class in pygame called image could not be found. Obviously pygame has not been installed properly so I would suggest using the above methods to install it again.

I hope this helps!"

Comment: How do I check what version of pygame I have

Comment: that should help - (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1345632/determine-if-an-executable-or-library-is-32-or-64-bits-on-windows ) [ or you could just use pip uninstall pygame and then install the correct version ]

Comment: That's confused me even more

Comment: what version of python do you have? (32 bit or 64  bit)

Comment: I have 64 but version 3.8.7

Comment: if you cannot check the version of library just simply run "pip uninstall pygame" and then install it correctly ([link](https://www.webucator.com/blog/2015/03/installing-the-windows-64-bit-version-of-pygame/))

Comment: then It propably won't be the solution in point A, try the other options maybe one of them will solve the problem.

Comment: "Unfortunately, Pygame doesn't have an official 64-bit installer, so they recommend you use the 32-bit version of Python" and that could be helpful too